# Would you save energy by heating the air in a shower stall so that you could use colder water?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

It is refreshing to take a cool shower in hot weather. And for the sake of discussion, lets assume that one should be "comfortable" with temeratures when taking a shower.

Considering that the vast majority of the heat from a shower is lost down the drain, would it not be more energy efficient to heat a confined space (shower stall) to a temperature that would allow you to shower with cool water rather than hot?

How hot would it have to be in the room for 70 degree water to be "nice." 60 degree?

And since all of the energy used to heat the air in the space would remain in the space/room, would you use less energy to take a comfortable shower doing it that way?

Comment: Nothing stops you from reusing most of the heat in the draining hot water.

Comment: @CuriousOne - True, but this doesn't address the question. IF it turns out that heating the air WOULD yield energy savings, then one could compare the savings to those from reusing the heat in the draining hot water. And then there would be the question of cost of both solutions.

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing the rather trivial calculation that shows that it doesn't and that you are better served by reusing the heat in the water. Just my two cents.

Comment: Apparently nothing stops you from snarky responses. I posted here because while the calculations are "rather trivial," to you, it would take me quite a bit of background research to do them. My hope is that the calculations would be so trivial to members of physics.stackexchange.com that I could get an answer without attitude.

Comment: What's snarky about giving you the correct answer?

Comment: If it is an answer, then it should be posted in Answers, not Comments. And quality Answers on Stack Exchange require more than someone saying "it does" or "it doesn't." So if you are going to answer the question, I request you show your work - or at least provide links to supporting info.

Comment: It's such a trivial answer that it doesn't really deserve to be one. It's much better left in comments. If someone wants to spend time on a trivial calculation, that's up to them. I do agree with you, though, that cold showers are refreshing. I do them all the time when I am in the tropics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34827/discussion-between-that-idiot-and-curiousone).

Comment: Hint for those who want to actually calculate this: Air temperature is not the actual problem and air is not what needs to be heated to feel comfortable or even hot in a room. It's the temperature of the walls that sets the radiation losses of the human body, which means that the heat in the hot water would have to be used to heat not just the air but also the surface of the walls. For any reasonable sized bathroom that's a losing proposition. Alternatively you can put mirrors on all walls... but that looks really awkward.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify that we're talking about a confined shower stall. Also that this question entered my mind when using a steam shower at a friend's house. I don't know what temperature the steam got to, but I do know that I was most comfortable using cooler water. But I had no way of measuring the temperature of the air nor the shower water. Would the temperature of the walls still control the radiation losses of the human body in such an environment?

Comment: @CuriousOne Do you really think that radiation is the primary heat transfer mechanism from the body to the surroundings?  If that were the case, then on  a cold day, the presence or absence of wind would have negligible effect on your skin temperature.  In my judgment (and experience) conduction and convection to the air are much more important than radiation.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: Yes, the temperature of the walls still controls how comfortable you feel. The human body has an area of about 2m^2. A black body at the body  temperature of humans would radiate about 1kW of power into empty space, i.e. we can only stay warm with our internal 100W heat source because our environment radiates almost as much radiation back as we lose. If you lower the radiation temperature of the environment to a mere 16 degrees C, the power we get back is 800W, i.e. we have basically no way of staying warm without clothing that reduces radiation losses.

Comment: This also explains why steam in the shower feels so good: it condenses on the walls and immediately raises their temperature very considerably. Warm air would not do this nearly as quickly and the radiation losses would make the shower feel cold.

Comment: It's funny how some people always post meaningless comments, but never answer the question. Perhaps to look inteligent?

Comment: @Pablo: You mean the OP didn't consider radiation? Yes, it's not something totally obvious, especially since high school science used to teach the wrong explanation for why we need clothing (to protect against cold air), at least when I was in high school. I hope that they are teaching the correct explanation now, that clothing protects against air and radiation losses. There are also some awesome black body calculators around like http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/radfrac.html. Give it a spin!

Comment: Sounds like using draining shower water to heat the walls might be a way to improve the feeling of warmth.

Comment: "Nothing stops you from reusing most of the heat in the draining hot water."... hey... didn't I write that in my first comment? Say, why didn't you like it the first time around and why are you plagiarizing it now?

Comment: Not plagiarizing - imitation - which, as you know, is the sincerest form of flattery. But it still doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Would you agree that my additional comments do and that they explain why I am not particularly interested in running trough the entire numerical argument with an example bathroom or a more general discussion? Like I said, if someone is willing to do the calculations, more power to them, I just don't see your suggestion as popping out as a general solution to saving energy. Even the heat exchanger will, as you obviously noticed, quickly turn into an engineering nightmare because of hair and human skin cells clogging its pipes. :-)

Comment: I mean the whole discussion doesn't relate much to the question

Comment: @Pablo: You would be correct, except that it actually answers it completely. Did you try that black body calculator, yet? After you do, you can write a complete answer for the OP and I will give you a +1 for your efforts. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne I would if I understood blackbody radiation...

Comment: @CuriousOne With all due respect, I still contend that conduction and convection dominate the heat transfer.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: You are welcome to run the numbers. I would also suggest that you do an experiment in a cold room with some aluminum foil or an aluminized mylar emergency blanket. Wrap the foil around an uncovered arm or a leg, leaving some distance for air. One can feel the difference due to the reflected heat quite easily. When I go into a cold outdoor environment I always take one of these with me... it could easily become the difference between life and death and they weigh next to nothing.

Comment: @Pablo: This is a great example to get an intuitive feeling for it. Seriously, punch a few numbers into that online calculator. You will be amazed how much radiation changes between room temperature and body temperature.

Comment: Hi again @CuriousOne.  I've done a little research on this, and it looks like to some degree, we're both right.  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rate+of+heat+loss+from+human+body.  According to the references I've seen, for typical temperature differences, the heat losses from naked bodies from radiation and convection are about on the same order.  I checked you 100 W value, and it seems about right.  So, I stand corrected.

Comment: @ChesterMiller - could you take a look at what I posted below. It's a starting place.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: Sounds about right. If this helps: Intuitively I didn't believe it initially myself, but radiation losses are a serious problem for humans, even in relatively mild temperatures.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35308/discussion-on-question-by-that-idiot-would-you-save-energy-by-heating-the-air-in).

Comment: Ha, I thought I moved it to chat on the first day it I posted it. Perhaps I don't have the cred to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Consider that the specific heat of water is 4.147 kJ/kg. The specific heat of air is less than 1/4 of that, so for the air to heat you as much as the water, you would have to heat the air to a much higher temperature. That's one reason, along with conduction, that Arctic explorers say that water cools you 30 times faster than air.

So it doesn't balance out. It's 4 times easier to heat air, but water cools you 30 times faster.

Even if this wasn't the case, your system would need to have a much higher temperature in it, which would mean more electricity, which would mean more electricity wasted in wires.

Comment: So say the "steam room" shower stall was brought up to 110 degrees F at 100% humidity. And say the water from the shower covers 40% of the skin at any given time (total guess for lack of actual info). How cool would you guess the water could be while still maintaining standard body temp?

Comment: Well, I see a problem already. If you maintain standard body temp, the water will not feel refreshing or warm. It will feel  (more or less) completely neutral.

Comment: Consider this: even in hot, humid weather, when it rains and the rain is cold, you can start getting cold. You certainly won't be enjoying a nice hot shower, even at 110 ºF, 100% humidity, and rain.

Comment: But it is very refreshing/nice to take a cool shower when it is hot out. I feel like you'd be no less comfortable showering with cool water when it is hot out than you would be showering with warm water when it is cool out. I suppose there is a lot of variation between personal tastes. I wonder what the relationship between ambient temp (or radiant heat input) and comfortable shower water temps is - there must be some predictable trend. In my steam room shower experience, I very quickly found that I didn't want the water hot.

Comment: So this would certainly ENHANCE your experience in a cold shower, because the relative temp would lower. (water temp relative to air temp). Notice: I said ENHANCE, not make cheaper. In the end, if you want a good cold shower experience you would do this, but you would burn a lot more energy.

Comment: But would you burn more energy than you would taking a comfortable hot shower in a cool room? I'm trying to pull together some numbers to throw out a back of the envelope calculation for you guys to rip up...

Answer (score 0):

According to a steam shower vendor, a 10KW unit is required to provide enough steam at 118 deg.F in a 6'x8'x 8' enclosure. The timer runs for 20 minutes (about right for a nice shower), so figure the unit would use 3.3KW and 2 gallons of water to make the steam room hot and steamy.

According to numbers pulled from all over, figure an average 20 min shower uses 50 gallons of water (416.5 lbs.), and that in my area that water comes out of the ground at 55 degrees F. To heat that water to 110 deg.F would take approx 22,910 BTU.

Converting KW to BTU (and here are the limits of my understanding - please correct my conversions/assumptions as needed) it looks like 3.3KW is about 11,260 BTU.

If this is all reasonable, then heating the shower to 82.5 deg.F would require 11,500 BTU, which, when added to the 11,260 BTU for the steam would total 22,760 BTU - or slightly less than just running the hot shower by itself. If you could go with heating the shower water even less,then the savings would appear to increase.

I am fully aware that this answer is full of broad assumptions, simplifications, and perhaps misunderstandings.